# linux/unix strace - add originating binary vs. shared library to log

Tags: linux, debugging, unix, strace

Is there an option to let 'strace' log the "location" of the executing code?

I would be interested to see **which** shared library - that is loaded by an executable - is executing the system calls. 
I'd like to have this option also for libraries that are not invoked by the loader, but by the executable itself via 'dlopen()'.

thanks!

regards, Frank

Comment: How about something more advanced like SystemTap? It can trace much more aspects of the system and what you asking seems to be solvable with `stap -v -e 'probe syscall.* { if(pid() == target()) { printf("%s(%s)", name, argstr); print_ubacktrace(); } }' -p PID`